# How to design multi-filters for a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, data-structures, data-binding

My Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

In my WPF Application, I want to bind a List to DataGridControl, the view also support filter by Sex and Country.

My current solution is Creating a List PersonList to store all the data and creating another List PersonBindingList to store the data should display in UI. When user check filters and click 'OK', using Linq to query from PersonList and assign the result to PersonBindingList to update UI.

But this should maintain two lists. Also, I don't want to load data every times when user change filter conditions, because the data volumne is very huge, the loading speed is very slow. Are there any other solutions? One more thing, Sex and Country could be free combined.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter data at client side, [`ICollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ([`ListCollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in particular) is what you want:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    // this is a property for filtering
    public bool Sex
    {
        get { ... }
        set
        {
            if (_sex != value) 
            {
                _sex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                PersonListView.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    // this is a property for filtering too
    public string Country
    {
        // call PersonListView.Refresh in setter, as in Sex property setter
    }  

    // this is a property for binding to DataGrid
    public ICollectionView PersonListView
    {
        get
        {
            if (_personListView == null)
            {
                _personList = LoadPersons();
                _personListView = new ListCollectionView(_personList)
                {
                    Filter = p => ShouldViewPerson((Person)p);
                }
            }
            return _personListView;
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldViewPerson(Person p)
    {
        // implement filtering logic here;
        // e.g.:
        return p.Country.StartsWith(Country) && p.Sex == Sex;
    }

    private ListCollectionView _personListView;
    private List<Person> _personList;
}
```

Collection views are some sort of projections, that is used for ordering, filtering and grouping source collections/sequences. You may think about them as about combination of LINQ's `Where`, `GroupBy`, `OrderBy` and `Select` methods, that will be applied to source collection, and resulting sequence, that will be bound to view.

By default, if you exposing some collection from view model, data binding engine creates default collection view for you. But if you want to get custom behavior, like filtering, you can build collection view yourself and expose it instead of collection.

> I don't want to load data every times when user change filter
>   conditions, because the data volumne is very huge, the loading speed
>   is very slow

If you can, consider filtering at server side. Client-side filtering is being performed in memory, and could consume a lot of system resources.

**UPDATE**

If you want multi-select countries from filtering list, you can replace scalar `Country` property to `Countries` collection and re-write filtering logic. Something like this:

```
// this is a filter item
public class CountryFilterItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string CountryName { ... }
    public bool IsChecked { ... }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    // this property is a replacement for "Country";
    // bind it to some ItemsControl is the filter view
    public IEnumerable<CountryFilterItem> Countries
    {
        get { return _countries; }
    }

    // fill filter somewhere;
    // when filling, subscribe on `PropertyChanged` event of each item;
    // when user will change IsChecked for item, you'll update filter:
    // 
    // var country = new Country { CountryName = "Zimbabwe" };
    // country.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
    // {
    //     if (propertyName == "IsChecked")
    //     {
    //         PersonListView.Refresh();
    //     }
    // };
    // _countries.Add(country);
    private List<CountryFilterItem> _countries;

    // filtering logic
    private bool ShouldViewPerson(Person p)
    {
        // implement filtering logic here;
        // e.g.:
        return _countries.Any(_ => _.IsChecked && _.CountryName == p.Country) && p.Sex == Sex;
    }

    // other code here...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dennis, thanks for you reply. In your code, Sex and Country are two property in the ViewModel, if my filter support multiple selection, where should I call Refresh method? For example, I want to show the Men in US and UK.